# Is it possible that some sort of CSS is preventing all full page screenshot plugins/tools from working on my web site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, screenshot

I need to take a full page screenshot (i.e. everything out of view must be in the screenshot too) of several pages of my website. However, something about my site is preventing screenshot functionalities, whether it be plugins, or built in tools like Firefox's command line screenshot feature, from working. They all only take screens of the visible area. I tested each with other web pages as well, and they work fine. This all leads me to believe that some sort of CSS or JS is making the screenshot tools bug out on my website. Any ideas of what to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the cause. I had:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

when I removed the `height: 100%;`, I was able to take the screenshot.

**Update**

I also recently found that fixed position elements are hidden by most screenshot software when taking a full page screen shot.